# How print lined from file by name in bash?

Tags: bash

how i can grep or cat file and print values by it names ?
for example: file os-release - i want print only NAME and VERSION

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian  
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

Comment: Use: `grep "^\(NAME\|VERSION\)=" yourfile`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print the lines containing `NAME` and `VERSION` entirely, you can use [`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep):

```
$ grep "^NAME=\|^VERSION=" /etc/*-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
```

Having `^` when grepping ensures that the words `NAME` and `VERSION` appear at the beginning of the line, so that you won't grep other lines such as `PRETTY_NAME`. The `=` ensures that you won't grep lines such as `VERSION_ID`.

If you just want to print the values of `NAME` and `VERSION`, however, you can do the following:

```
$ grep "^NAME=\|^VERSION=" /etc/*-release | grep -E -o ".[a-z]\w+"
Ubuntu
Trusty 
Tahr
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your text file name is test.txt. Then run following command for name and version lines only

```
cat test.txt | grep "NAME\|VERSION"
```

For complete value as you informaed in comments

```
cat text.txt | grep "NAME=\"Ubuntu\"\|VERSION=\"14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr\""
```

Comment: You could written as : `grep 'NAME\|VERSION' test.txt`. `grep` can read inputs from files.

Comment: How to specify the absolute values ? I need only 

      'NAME="Ubuntu" 
       VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"


    grep 'NAME\|VERSION' /etc/os-release 
    NAME="Ubuntu"
    VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
    PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
    VERSION_ID="14.04"'